# How to find min and max in dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr

1. I know the sum of points for each person.
2. I need to know: what is the minimum number of points that a person could have. And what is the maximum number of points that a person could have.

What I have tried:

```
min_and_max <- dataset %>%
 group_by(person) %>%
 dplyr::filter(min(sum(points, na.rm = T))) %>%
 distinct(person) %>%
 pull()
 min_and_max
```

My dataset:

```
id   person   points
201  rt99   NA
201  rt99   3
201  rt99   2
202  kt     4
202  kt     NA
202  kt     NA
203  rr     4
203  rr     NA
203  rr     NA
204  jk     2
204  jk     2
204  jk     NA
322  knm3   5
322  knm3   NA
322  knm3   3
343  kll2   2
343  kll2   1
343  kll2   5
344  kll    NA
344  kll    7
344  kll    1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest this `dplyr` approach. You have to summarize data like this:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Code
df %>% group_by(id,person) %>%
  summarise(Total=sum(points,na.rm = T),
            min=min(points,na.rm = T),
            max=max(points,na.rm=T))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 7 x 5
# Groups:   id [7]
     id person Total   min   max
  <int> <chr>  <int> <int> <int>
1   201 rt99       5     2     3
2   202 kt         4     4     4
3   203 rr         4     4     4
4   204 jk         4     2     2
5   322 knm3       8     3     5
6   343 kll2       8     1     5
7   344 kll        8     1     7
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the data.table solution -

```
dataset[, min_points := min(points, na.rm = T), by = person]
dataset[, max_points := max(points, na.rm = T), by = person]
```

Since I don't have your data, I cannot test this code, but it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

The `summarize()` verb is what you want for this. You don't even need to filter out the `NA` values first since both `min()` and `max()` can have `na.rm = TRUE`.

```
library(dplyr)
min_and_max <- dataset %>%
  group_by(person) %>%
  summarize(min = min(points, na.rm = TRUE),
            max = max(points, na.rm = TRUE))
min_and_max
# A tibble: 7 x 3
 person   min   max
  <chr>  <dbl> <dbl>
1 jk         2     2
2 kll        1     7
3 kll2       1     5
4 knm3       3     5
5 kt         4     4
6 rr         4     4
7 rt99       2     3

dput(dataset)
structure(list(id = c(201, 201, 201, 202, 202, 202, 203, 203, 
203, 204, 204, 204, 322, 322, 322, 343, 343, 343, 344, 344, 344
), person = c("rt99", "rt99", "rt99", "kt", "kt", "kt", "rr", 
"rr", "rr", "jk", "jk", "jk", "knm3", "knm3", "knm3", "kll2", 
"kll2", "kll2", "kll", "kll", "kll"), points = c(NA, 3, 2, 4, 
NA, NA, 4, NA, NA, 2, 2, NA, 5, NA, 3, 2, 1, 5, NA, 7, 1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-21L), spec = structure(list(cols = list(id = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), person = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), points = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector")), skip = 1), class = "col_spec"))
```